# 1Tb Seagate Backup Plus Drive: It shows the drive as empty but has used half of available space

Tags: hard-drive

Im using an Ubuntu environment and used this harddrive to move files from my CPU to the external hard drive.  Everything was going fine for awhile, as I was able to copy, move, view, and access files from the external hard drive.  Then one day, it showed the folder as "empty".  But if you check properties of the external hard drive, it shows that it has used almost 400gb of data, so I know based on that information that something is there.

Funny thing is when I move this external hard drive to a PC based system, i'm able to view the files.  But, back onto the ubuntu system, i cannot.  Please help!

UPDATE from comments:

```
$ mount
/dev/sdb1 o n/media/matcha/Segate Backup Plus Drive type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0, group_id=0, default_permissions, allow_other, blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

$ fdisk -l
Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type 
/dev/sda1 * 2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G 83 Linux 
Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type 
/dev/sdb1 2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/media/matcha/Seagate Backup Plus Drive$ ls 
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error 
/media/matcha/Seagate Backup Plus Drive$ ls -a 
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

Comment: Your hard drive may not have mounted in the directory you are checking. Can you post output of commands - mount and fdisk -l ?

Comment: mount:   /dev/sdb1 o n/media/matcha/Segate Backup Plus Drive type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0, group_id=0, default_permissions, allow_other, blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: fdisk -l:

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G 83 Linux

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: Sorry, I can't fit the whole thing on this comments line.  I can only add snippets.  let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I can see the disk being mounted on /media/matcha/Segate Backup Plus Drive. Are you able to see your files from terminal? e.g. ls -a  /media/matcha/Segate Backup Plus Drive ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to included the requested information. Do not post it in comments.

Comment: No, this is what i'm getting...

root@matcha-desktop:/media/matcha/Seagate Backup Plus Drive# ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
root@matcha-desktop:/media/matcha/Seagate Backup Plus Drive# ls -a
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

The

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

means that there's a problem with the filesystem.  This could be with the filesystem itself (corrupt filesystems tables), or the disk itself (hardware failure).

Unmount the drive first

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

carefully checking it doesn't throw an error.  If it throws no warning, do a filesystem check. It's an NTFS partition, so you can try

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`

or plug it into a Windows machine and run a partition verify there.

If that doesn't work, open another window and type:

`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`

and leave it open.  This will show you the logs relating to what you are trying.

Then go back to your original window and type `ls` again.

What you will see in the log is a reason for the error.  Depending on the type of failure this may be alot of log lines.   Please try to isolate the actual error and put it in your question.

Comment: Hi Tudor,
I did the unmount, but then then it said "target is busy", so I did an "umount -l /dev/sdb1" and then the "sudo umount /dev/sdb1", and it seemed to process OK.  The drive is now unmounted.  I then ran the sudo ntsfix /dev/sdb1 and it showed that it ran successfully

-  Mounting volume ok
- Process of SMFT...etc etc completed successfully
- NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully...

After doing all that, is it supposed to work?  It still showing that  error

Comment: "Target is busy" usually means that you have a window or software that is open at that directory.  I've added an explanation to my answer to find the logs relating to your error.